# Turn off display when inactive not working; xset dpms force off only turns off for a few seconds

Tags: settings, display

I'm using Elementary OS 7 and have the following settings:

- Turn off display when inactive for: 5 minutes
- Suspend when inactive for: Never
- Lock after screen turns off: Off

The screen does not turn off after 5 minutes of inactivity.

A workaround would be to have some way to turn the screen off myself. Running `xset dpms force off` turns off the screen, but it turns back on by itself after about 10 seconds, so that doesn't work.

I found one forum online suggesting to install Light Locker Settings, but I can't find this from the app center or anywhere... if anyone has clues on how to go about that workaround please let me know.